# Jenkins Multiple Builds On Single Job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

On Jenkins is there a way to setup a job to have two distinct builds that can be triggers for different reasons.

As an example

(1) First build handles releases and is only started manually.

(2) Second build runs automatically every time a commit occurs.

I know that I can split this into two different jobs each with its only build and triggers however I prefer not to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the builds have anything in common? If they share the same build process, but the release requires extra pre/post-build steps, then [**Release Plugin**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Release+Plugin) is exactly what you need.

It allows to define additional pre/post-build steps that are executed only when manually triggering a release build.

However this goes against the CI concept. In CI, your eventually-released-build would have been promoted from a regular automatic CI build.